# Добрый день, ради интереса решил написать 27 задачу с ЕГЭ по информатике на JS

Tags: javascript

Переменная s на выходе вместо числового значения выдает NaN, помогите разобраться, почему так получается, пожалуйста.

https://yandex.ru/tutor/subject/problem/?problem_id=T4919

```
let N, x, chet, nechet, O, five, s = 0;
let a = [];
N = prompt("Введите количество чисел");
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  a[i] = prompt("Введите число");
}
for (let i = 10; i < N; i++) {
  x = prompt("Введите число");
  if (a[i % 10] == 0) O++;
  else if (a[i % 2] == 0) chet++;
  else if (a[i % 5] == 0) five++;
  else nechet++;
  if (x % 10 == 0) s += five + nechet + chet + O;
  else if (x % 5 == 0) s += chet + O;
  else if (x % 2 != 0) s += O;
  else if (x % 2 == 0) s += O + five;
}

document.write(s);
```

Comment: Инициализирована только s?

Comment: Да. Другие переменные требуется инициализировать?

Comment: Да, требуется .

Comment: А еще, prompt возвращает строку, даже если туда вводят число... на всякий случай хорошо бы как можно раньше превратить строку в число, чтобы не было сюрпризов... `x = Number( prompt("введите число") )`

Comment: P.s. может скопируете и задачу в вопрос?) Она решена на JS, но в стиле Паскаля) Может предложат и другие варианты решения.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, NaN больше не появляется. Теперь код выводит значение s, заданное переменной при инициализации, а должен 1 выдавать при входных из условия.

Comment: Вы не поняли смысла задания.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось:

```js
'use strict';

let chet = 0;
let N = prompt('Введите ко-во чисел.', '');
//Ввод чисел через запятую, например 1,5,5,8,9,4,12,14,6,7,9,8
let a = prompt('Введите числа.', '').split(',');

//Цикл, который проходит по всем эл. массива,
//при этом, если уже не с чем сравнивать,
//то есть не существует i + 10, то стоп
for ( let i = 0; !isNaN(a[i + 10]); i++ ) {

 // Цикл, который проходит по всем парам
 //с разницей 10 и больше
 for ( let j = i + 10; !isNaN(a[j]); j++ ) {

  //Проверка на условие.
  //Если непонятно, раскомментируйте это и поймете:
  //alert( `${i} число равно ${a[i]}, а ${j} = ${a[j]}` );
  if ( a[i + 10] * a[i] % 10 == 0 ) {
   chet++;
  }
 }

}

alert(chet);
```

Я все расписал и по-моему проще писать числа через запятую: 1,5,5,8,9,4,12,14,6,7,9,8.

Comment: Спасибо за интересное решение, видно, что мышление человека, понимающего JS, отличается от моего. Но не уверен, что этот код подойдет под максимальный балл на экзамене, т.к. "не эффективна по времени" в моем понимании, то есть при большом количестве чисел(цикл в цикле, все такое).